# concatenate using vba array

Tags: excel, vba

I have a situation where I would like to merge two columns in to one.

Example : column 2 and 3 data should get merged in column 1 (column 1 is empty). column 2 is string while column 3 has date.

I can use concatenate function. However, I would like to use array in order to boost the speed.

Comment: What have you tried so far? and what issues are you facing?

Answer (score 0):

Try:(adjust to your range(s)

```
[A1:A5] = [B1:B5&" "&TEXT(C1:C5,"DD-MM-YYYY")]
```